# Show Posts From Same Category OR Same Tag

Tags: query-posts

Assume a post is categorized in "Fruit" and tagged with "Apple".
The following code shows posts with category "Fruit" AND tag "Apple"

```
$args = array(  
    'tag__in' => $tag_in,  
    'category__in' => $category_in,  
);
query_posts($args);
```

How to show all posts which are from either category "Fruit" OR tag "Apple"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that with a `tax_query` with `OR` relation. [See the Taxonomy Parameters section for `WP_Query` in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for the different tax query parameters.

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'fruit' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'apple' )
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In the above example we've created a new `WP_Query` instance instead of using `query_posts()`. This is the correct method if this is an *additional query* aside from the page's *main query*.

If this is the *main query*, see the [`pre_get_posts` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for how to add these parameters to the main query *before* the query is sent to the database.

[Read this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/4771) for info on the various query methods available and [read this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/4771) for info on why you shouldn't use `query_posts()`.